# github-action: does the IF have an ELSE?

Tags: github-actions

in github action
I have an if, but I still need to run someother thing if I'm in the else case. Is there a clean way to do it or do I have to do another step with the same condition at false?

```
 - if: contains(['SNAPSHOT'],env.BUILD_VERSION)
   name:IF
   run: echo ":)"
 - if: false == contains(['SNAPSHOT'], env.BUILD_VERSION)
   name: Else
   run: echo ":("
```

Comment: I have a somehow similar issue and I'm really curious about how you integrated this in your jobs, could you add a link to your GitHub config file or add a bit more context?

Answer (score 53, accepted):

GitHub Actions doesn't have *else* statement to run a different command/action/code. But you're right, all what you need to do is to create another step with reversed *if* condition. BTW, you can just use `!` instead of `false ==`, if you surround your statement with `${{ }}`.

Here are some links: [if statement](https://help.github.com/en/actions/reference/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions#jobsjob_idif), [operators](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/learn-github-actions/expressions#operators)

Comment: so you cannot have multiple `if` in a single `steps.name`?

Comment: @DanChaltiel I don't think so

Comment: You can't use `!`, that's not valid YAML syntax. Why would you write that without testing it?

Comment: @Peter You can use `!` if you write your condition in `${{ }}` brackets. [Here](https://github.com/fabasoad/twilio-voice-call-action/actions/runs/440407309/workflow#L24) is an example

Comment: @DanChaltiel see my comment which can be useful in your case: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66109820/4298115

Comment: @Peter, you can use ! just not at the start of the condition. `if: success() && !contains(['SNAPSHOT'], env.BUILD_VERSION)` will work, but `if: !contains(['SNAPSHOT'], env.BUILD_VERSION)` will not.

Comment: YOU CAN NOW HAVE ELSE
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60916931/github-action-does-the-if-have-an-else

Answer (score 31):

You can do the following which would only run the script where the condition passes:

```
job_name:
  runs-on: windows-latest
  if: "!contains(github.event.head_commit.message, 'SKIP SCRIPTS')"    <--- skips everything in this job if head commit message does not contain 'SKIP SCRIPTS'

  steps:
    - uses: ....
  
    - name: condition 1
      if: "contains(github.event.head_commit.message, 'CONDITION 1 MSG')"
      run: script for condition 1

   - name: condition 2
      if: "contains(github.event.head_commit.message, 'CONDITION 2 MSG')"
      run: script for condition 2
```

and so on. Of course you would use your own condition here.

Answer (score 17):

You may consider using the [haya14busa/action-cond](https://github.com/marketplace/actions/conditional-value-for-github-action) action. It is useful when the `if-else` operation is needed to set dynamic configuration of other steps (don't need to duplicate the whole step to set different values in a few parameters).

Example:

```yaml
- name: Determine Checkout Depth
  uses: haya14busa/action-cond@v1
  id: fetchDepth
  with:
    cond: ${{ condition }}
    if_true: '0'  # string value
    if_false: '1' # string value
- name: Checkout
  uses: actions/checkout@v2
  with:
    fetch-depth: ${{ steps.fetchDepth.outputs.value }}
```

Comment: A third party dependency that requires updates, might have security vulnerabilities, etc., just for `if`...

Answer (score 17):

Alternative solution to github actions based commands, is to use shell script commands for if else statement.

On Ubuntu machine,example workflow to check if commit has a tag or not,

```
runs-on: ubuntu-latest
steps:
  - uses: actions/checkout@v2
  - run: |
      ls
      echo ${{ github.ref }}
      ref='refs/tags/v'
      if [[ ${{ github.ref }} == *${ref}* ]]; then
        v=$(echo ${{ github.ref }} | cut -d'/' -f3)
        echo "version tag is ${v}"
      else
        echo "There is no github tag reference, skipping"
      fi
```

Answer (score 16):

I found that we could also use expression for that here how I did it:

```
jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    env:
      PkgDesc: ${{ github.event.inputs.packageDescription != '' && github.event.inputs.packageDescription ||  format('{0} - {1}', 'Commit', github.SHA)  }}
```

Syntax: ${{ x && 'ifTrue' || 'ifFalse'  }}

More details https://github.com/actions/runner/issues/409#issuecomment-752775072

Comment: This should be the accepted answer

Answer (score -1):

You can also do something like this if you want to check for some data type value without using built in functions

```bash
- name: Notify Team on Slack
   if: ${{github.repository == 'calebcadainoo/cascade-img'}}
   run: |
     # some command
```

Over here, I'm triggering event on each push.

I'm pushing to two repos at the same time but I only want to run my command once.

Read More on Expressions Here:

https://docs.github.com/en/actions/learn-github-actions/expressions