# Github Workflow Matrix Contion PHP Version Composer Require

Tags: github, github-actions

I'm trying to build a composer library that I would like to be compatible back to PHP 7.0 but for this to work I need to use different PHPUnit versions.

I am trying to update the require component based on if-statements, but either none of them or all of them run. I don't really understand why.

I have tried to take inspiration from this post:
[github-action: does the IF have an ELSE?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60916931/github-action-does-the-if-have-an-else)

```bash
name: PHP CI

on:
  pull_request:
    branches:
      - "master"
  workflow_dispatch:

jobs:
  render-php:
    runs-on: ${{ matrix.operating-system }}
    strategy:
      fail-fast: false
      matrix:
        operating-system: ["ubuntu-latest"]
        php-versions: ["7.0", "7.4", "8.0"]
        phpunit-versions: ["latest"]
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v3
        with:
          fetch-depth: 0
      - run: git merge origin/master --no-commit --ff-only
      - uses: shivammathur/setup-php@v2
        with:
          php-version: ${{ matrix.php-versions }}
          extensions: mbstring, intl
          ini-values: post_max_size=256M, max_execution_time=180
          coverage: xdebug
          tools: phpunit:${{ matrix.phpunit-versions }}
      - run: echo "${{ matrix.php-versions }}"
      - name: "PHP 7.0"
        if: "${{ matrix.php-versions }} == 7.0"
        run: composer require --dev --with-all-dependencies --no-install phpunit/phpunit 6.0
      - name: "PHP 7.4"
        if: "${{ matrix.php-versions }} == 7.4"
        run: composer require --dev --with-all-dependencies --no-install phpunit/phpunit 8.0
      - name: "PHP >8.0"
        if: "${{ matrix.php-versions }} >= 8.0"
        run: composer require --dev --with-all-dependencies --no-install phpunit/phpunit
      - run: composer install
      - run: ./vendor/bin/phpunit
```

What exactly am I doing wrong or not understanding properly?

Answer (score 0):

It was me who did not understand the way IF-statements worked, it should be states as such instead:

```bash
if: ${{ matrix.php-versions == 7.0 }}
```